# Find $\sum_{j = 1}^{2004} i^{2004 - F_j}$ where $F_n$ is the nth Fibonacci number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, summation, fibonacci-numbers

The Fibonacci sequence is defined by $F_1 = F_2 = 1$ and $F_n = F_{n - 1} + F_{n - 2}$ for $n \ge 3.$

Compute
$$\displaystyle\sum_{j = 1}^{2004} i^{2004 - F_j}.$$

---

I tried computing the first few values of $i^{2004 - F_j}$, and I got
\begin{align*}
&j=1:i^{2004-1}=-i\\
&j=2:i^{2004-1}=-i\\
&j=3:i^{2004-2}=-1\\
&j=4:i^{2004-3}=i\\
&j=5:i^{2004-5}=-i\\
&j=6:i^{2004-8}=1\\
&j=7:i^{2004-13}=-i\\
&j=8:i^{2004-21}=-i.\\
\end{align*}
However, I don't really see a pattern or anything, and I'm not sure how find the sum. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

1. $F_j \pmod 4$ is a function of $j \pmod 6$. In particular, $F_j=1$ if $j \pmod 6 =1$; $F_j=1$ if $j \pmod 6 =2$; $F_j=2$ if $j \pmod 6 =3$; $F_j=3$ if $j \pmod 6 =4$; $F_j=1$ if $j \pmod 6 =5$; $F_j=0$ if $j \pmod 6 =0$. Thus, can you see a likewise pattern for $2004-F_j$.
2. $6|2004$.

You should get:

> $\frac{2004}{6} \times (-i-i-1+i-i+1) = 334 \times (-2i)$.

Comment: Thanks!! Also, isn't it $334\cdot (-2i)$?

Comment: @MathMagician you are correct, $2004/6=334$, not $368$, my mistake!